# Behavior of the sequences as n tends to infinity

Tags: limits, infinity

I'm trying to figure out the behavior of some sequences in the following cases.

The next two can be found in Hardy's "A Course of Pure Mathematics" (p. 131).

If $\phi(n) \to +\infty$ and $\psi(n) \to -\infty$, then

1) $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} (\phi(n) + \psi(n)) = 0$ if $\phi(n) = n$ and $\psi(n) = -n$

2) $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} (\phi(n) + \psi(n)) = \infty$ if $\phi(n) = n^2$ and $\psi(n) = -n$

In the first case, if $n-n$ were simply numbers, then I could substract them and obtain a constant sequence which has the same limit. However, I'm considering this case as a limit, so I'm not quite sure I can operate with the expression under the limit as with simple numbers.

In the second case, I could make the following transformation $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} (n^2-n) = \lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} n^2 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{n})$, but as far as I understand, I can't use the property $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} x(n) \cdot y(n) = \lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} x(n) \cdot \lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} y(n)$ because $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} n^2 = +\infty$. So it's like in the case of, for example, $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} (\sqrt{n^2+n} - n)$ where the similar transformation $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} (n \cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - n)$ leads me to the same indeterminate form $"\infty-\infty"$ (but here I can get rid of it with help of the conjugate multiplier $(\sqrt{n^2+n} + n$)).

So, I'm confused of how can I deal with the indeterminate form of type $"\infty-\infty"$ and would like to find a way to solve this by only using the *basic* properties of the limits.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a typo on the first case? $\psi(n)=n$, no?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez sorry, there should be $\phi(n) + \psi(n)$ instead of substraction. Fixed it.

Comment: You can say $\lim x(n)y(n) = \lim x(n) \lim y(n)$ because $\lim y(n)$ exists and is finite and non-zero.  If the limit of the product existed and were finite, then $\lim x(n)$ would be the quotient of two limits that exist and are finite.  So $\lim x(n)y(n)$ must be infinite.

Comment: Can you use L'Hôpital's rule? Otherwise, you can prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}c\cdot x(n)=c\lim_{x\to\infty}x(n)$ even if $x(n)\to \infty$, and then use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y(n)=1=c$

Comment: @RobertShore just explained this with more detail, thanks!

Comment: @RobertShore then, according to your logic, $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} (n \cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - n) = 0$ which isn't correct... I thought myself it could work, but when I do this, it leads me to the wrong answer as $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} ( \sqrt{n^2+{n}} - n)=-\frac{1}{2}$...

Comment: No, because now you are trying to take the difference of two infinite limits.  My argument works only when all but (possibly) one of your limits exist and are finite (and sometimes you also need non-zero).  My logic does show that $\lim n \sqrt{1+ \frac 1n}$ is infinite, but that doesn't help you because $\lim n$ also is infinite.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez, I wouldn't like to use L'Hôpital's rule, just want to get the result explicitly by using the basic properties of limits. Moreover, if I follow that logic for $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} ( \sqrt{n^2+{n}} - n)$, I will get $0$ instead of $-\frac{1}{2}$ as  $\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} ( n \cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} - n)=\lim_\limits{n \to +\infty} ( n - n) = 0$

Comment: @RobertShore, yeah, that's right. But I'm interested exactly in cases when I have a "substraction" of infinities.

Comment: Perhaps a similar technique from the one you are proposing is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(n)+\psi(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2(1-1/n^2)}{1+1/n}$$

Notice that this is of the form $\lim_{n\to\infty}x(n)y(n)$ where $y(n)=\frac{(1-1/n^2)}{1+1/n}$ and hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}y(n)=1$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x(n)y(n)=\lim x(n)=\infty$

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez, yes, I guess this one will really work. So the only confusing case is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (n-n)$. If I apply the same technique, there will still be the indeterminate form of "$\infty \cdot 0$", $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \cdot (1-1)}{2}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formal definition of limit? Would like to include in an answer, perhaps.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez sure! Do you simply want to write $|n-n-0| < \epsilon$ and "prove" $\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} (n-n) = 0$?

Comment: As in your example of $\lim (\sqrt{n^2-n}-n)$, those problems often are solved by converting them to a quotient that *is* in the necessary form.  In that case, multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}$ and then divide top and bottom of the resulting fraction by $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the functions, so that $\phi(n) + \psi(n) = n - n = 0$ for all $n$.  Then take the limit.  That is exactly what $$\lim_{n\to\infty}( \phi(n)+\psi(n) ) $$ is defined to mean.

In the second case, again you are right:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\phi(n) + \psi(n)) = n^2 - n. $$

At this stage you do not need to apply the limit of a product but simply note that once $n > 2$, $n^2 - n > n$ so the right hand side approaches $\infty$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes, it makes sense. So, in the first case, I can at first take the sum of 2 functions and then evaluate the limit while this approach would be wrong $\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} n - \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} n$ because it leads me nowhere (I mean, I can apply the sum property of the limits but it won't give me an effect). I would like to clarify if my conclusion is correct.

Comment: Correct:  the approach fails in both cases, because neither $\phi$ nor $\psi$ have limits and then the limit of the sum (which is what you want) is not equal to the sum of the limits.  This is a case, by design, where the limit of the sum is easier to deal with than the sum of the limits.

Comment: Now it’s clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an answer with aims of explaining why the approach suggested in the comments does not work every time. I present three observations:

1. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=c>0$. Then:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)g(n)\to c\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) \to \infty$$

(I can provide a formal proof below, if needed).

2. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=0$. Then we cannot be conclusive about  $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)g(n)$, since it is of the form $0\cdot \infty$.
3. Consider the function

   $$r(n;k)=n\sqrt{c+1/n}-n=n(\sqrt{k+1/n}-1)=f(n)\cdot g(n)$$

Where $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=\sqrt{c+1/n}-1$. Notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=\sqrt{k}-1$.

This means that for $k>1$, it is the case that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)g(n)\to (\sqrt{k}-1)\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) \to \infty$$.

However, if $k=1$ the limit is of the form $0\cdot\infty$ and hence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)g(n)\neq (\sqrt{k}-1)\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) =0$$.

Notice that $k=1$ represents the counter example you are providing, however for $n^2-n=n^2(1-1/n^2)$ this problem does not arise since $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-1/n^2)=1\neq 0$ and hence

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n(1-1/n^2)\to 1\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}n\to \infty$$